# Recover permanently deleted folder

Tags: windows, recover

I have a web project which I store in htdocs folder of XAMPP. But several months ago, I cleaned my computer and accidentally deleted the XAMPP folder but I didn't realize that. I did try every recovery software I found on the internet (EASEUS, Disk Drill,....) but they can recover almost my files except that file in htdocs folder. It doesn't seem to exist on my laptop. What can I do to recover it?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but there does not seem to be a way, at least I don't think so. Especially the fact that you said `several months ago` was when you cleaned your computer, it is long gone by now. Remember that the files in your htdocs are saved on your local machine, not in another server. I am sure you know that already as you will need to type `localhost/.../` when you want to connect to that directory.

Unless you did a `Windows System Restore` on your `C drive`, there is no other way, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I really want this project, poor me :(